# Vagrant up any alternative

Tags: git, vagrant, git-bash

I was setting up vagrant  for the first time,
I used Vagrant up few times but , it didnt finished , before finishing I am getting error like

```
HTTP server doesn't seem to support byte ranges. Cannot resume.
```

at 15%
and

```
SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 10054
```

at 81%

is there any other way I can download the contents like any zip or image file?

so that I can paste the content at ".vagrant.d" folder?

Answer (score 0):

you mean like you could not download a box ? you can try to download the box alone first with following

```
vagrant box add --insecure <name of your box>
```

it should pass the `SSL read` error

Answer (score 0):

#### Clean Download

You may be running into an [issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/4479) that will be fixed in the 1.8 release. Rather than updating, you can also try the following to bypass the partial download cache:

```
vagrant box add <box name> --clean
```

#### Downloading Manually

If you really want to download the box manually though, here's how:

- Find the URL of the box you want to download. It will be in the format:
  `https://atlas.hashicorp.com/<username>/boxes/<boxname>`.
- After visiting that url, click the version number you want to download. You should now be at:
  `https://atlas.hashicorp.com/<username>/boxes/<boxname>/versions/<version>`.
- Next, append the provider you want to download:
  `/providers/<provider>.box`.
- Finally, import the box into Vagrant:
  `vagrant box add --name "<user>/<boxname>" /path/to/download.box`

#### Manual Example

As an example, here's how you'd import the current version of ubuntu/trusty64 for VirtualBox:

```
wget -O /tmp/ubuntu.box https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64/versions/20151208.1.0/providers/virtualbox.box
vagrant box add --name "ubuntu/trusty64" /tmp/ubuntu.box
rm /tmp/ubuntu.box
```

Just note that the box won't be linked to the version in atlas, and won't have a version number. You could try linking it with the metadata_url, but I haven't tested this:

```
echo "https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/trusty64" > ~/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-trusty64/metadata_url
```